# Convert PHP regex to c#

Tags: c#, php, regex

I have this regex:

```
<DIV(?:(?!</DIV>).)*?"(http://www\.foo\.com(?:\\.|[^"\\])*)"
```

And I am trying to use it using c#:

```
 @"<DIV(?:(?!</DIV>).)*?""(http://www\.foo\.com(?:\\.|[^""\\])*)"""
```

But this outputs
every thing from `<DIV` onward I want it to just show inside the `""`

**Like the actual regex does**

Comment: Firstly: Use a library to do this. Regex isn't built for this. Second: How are you retrieving the value it captures? Via `Groups[0]`? The first group is always everything.

Comment: @Simon Whitehead: "Firstly: Use a library to do this" --- there is no "*The Library*" thing over there, you probably mean "some HTML parsing library"?

Comment: @zerkms Indeed. I thought that was implied, given the task is HTML parsing. "A library" refers to a library for the task.. HTML parsing. I'll be more explicit next time :)

Comment: @Maximilian Show us how you retrieve the value...

Comment: Show us the C# you've written to "output everything from `<DIV` onward".

Comment: Groups[0] is going to catch more than what you want. Try Groups[1]? I'd answer but Simon Whitehead intuited the problem already and deserves the credit ;)

Comment: @Maximilian seriously, just get CsQuery from NuGet, this is not an 'easy' question since you can't parse HTML with regex - it's not a regular language and you can have comments inside the div, or things you would not expect. With CsQuery this is a simple, straightforward, one liner.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead answered it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using capture groups (groups between a pair of parentheses `()`), you will have to use `Groups[#]` to get the different parts of the capture group. `Groups[1]` will have the value of the first capture group.

If you are using:

```
@"<DIV(?:(?!</DIV>).)*?""(http://www\.foo\.com(?:\\.|[^""\\])*)"""
```

You will get the ones between `"` by using `Groups[1].Value` and the whole match in `Groups[0].Value`.

Example:

```
@"a(b(cd)(ef))"
```

Here you have 3 capture groups because there are 3 pairs of parentheses. After a match, and if you use:

```
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[0].Value);
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[2].Value);
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[3].Value);
```

You get:

```
abcdef
bcdef
cd
ef
```

If that's a little confusing, maybe this breakdown can help:

```
a(b(cd)(ef))
 1 2   3
   ^--|^--|
 ^---------|
```

The numbers and `^` indicate the beginning of the capture groups.

Comment: Hey @Jerry me again! Can you add to the `<DIV(?:(?!</DIV>).)*?"(http://www\.foo\.com(?:\\.|[^"\\])*)"` that the line must contain the string `high_res_link`

Comment: @Maximilian Like within the link `www.foo.com...`?

Comment: @Maximilian: `@"<DIV(?=(?:(?!</DIV>).)*high_res_link)(?:(?!</DIV>).)*?"(http://www\.foo\.com(?:\\.|[^"\\])*)"` This one uses a positive lookahead.

Answer (score 1):

```cs
string str = "<DIV src=\"http://www.foo.com\"></DIV>";
Regex re = new Regex(@"<DIV(?:(?!<\/DIV>).)*?\""(http:\/\/www\.foo\.com(?:\\.|[^\""\\])*)\""");
// or Regex re = new Regex(@"<DIV(?:(?!</DIV>).)*?""(http://www\.foo\.com(?:\\.|[^""\\])*)""");

Match match = re.Match(str);
Console.Write(match.Groups[1]); // Returns "http://www.foo.com"
```